# Cockpit for Yakkety

Tags: 16.10

So I've decided to give [Cockpit](http://cockpit-project.org/) a try, turns out there is no repository for Yakkety, only for Xenial and older releases. Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the PPA for cockpit to your system and set it up to install from Xenial. Open up software&updates and add ...

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cockpit-project/cockpit/ubuntu xenial main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cockpit-project/cockpit/ubuntu xenial main
```

to "other software", update your system and do a ...

```
sudo apt install cockpit
```

Slight warning: it is not advised to mix operating systems. Always be aware of this when you do this and always keep an eye out that the PPA might get upgraded to your OS.